# Do Emirates provides extra services when you have long layover in Dubai airport?

Tags: airports, layovers, dubai, emirates

I will take Emirates flights (Economic class) on 20th AUG and have 10 hours layover in Dubai airport.

[Tripadvisors reviews](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g295424-d3919850-Reviews-McDonald_s-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html)  mentions that Emirates will provide some McDonald coupons if you have long layover. Is that true? And how long of layover do they give the coupon? And what other things do they provide?

Comment: I had a 23 hour layover once, didn't get anything, but also didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may qualify for "[Dubai Connect](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/dubai-connect/dubai-connect.aspx)", which would provide you meals, accommodation, transporation, if your itinerary matches certain conditions (layover length between 8 and 24 hours, no better connections available and there are a few more limitations).

If your booking does qualify, then you should see it as an option on Emirates website under "Manage your booking".